# How to start shared element transition between 2 activity?

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I just learn about Shared Element in Android and I have one image which one of them in `ActivitySplashScreen` and one other is into `Toolbar` and I want to use shared element to move this image from `ActivitySplashScreen` to `ActivityMain`

after some search and try to implement that simple way to make this feature don't work on my code, for example:

**style.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**ActivitySplashScreen.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivitySplashScreen.this,
                            app_logo,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(app_logo));
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

**ActivityMain.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    supportPostponeEnterTransition();
}
```

and `ImageView` widget on my `ActivitySplashScreen` and `ActivityMain` xml layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/instagram_add_story"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_wizard_1"
    android:transitionName="app_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

this code is not working as well and I'm not sure what exactly problem on that

**UPDATED**

`ActivitySplashScreen` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alachiq_header_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram_animation_gradient_list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:transitionName="app_logo"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_wizard_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_light"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar.Light">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_bold"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/application_logo"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/application_logo"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
                    android:transitionName="app_logo"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/drawerMenu"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try to explore this link:- https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

Comment: @DolDurma please share the XML files of both activities.

Comment: @TanveerMunir post updated

Comment: @DolDurma are you using ImageView in app bar layout In MainActivity is that requirement?

Comment: @TanveerMunir I'm trying to move imageview from `ActivitySplashScreen` to toolbar on `ActivityMain`

Comment: @DolDurma are you setting the toolbar in mainActivity??

Comment: I think you are not setting the toolbar and not getting ImageView from the toolbar in mainActivity. @DolDurma

Comment: @TanveerMunir did you have any simple sample code to khnow how can i implementing that?

Comment: I have sample code but not according to your scenario I will post it tomorrow

Comment: @DolDurma I will try to code according to your scenario.

Comment: @DolDurma I post my answer according to your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use in this way here is my solution according to your scenario.

**Style:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Splash.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alachiq_header_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Splash.Java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.app_logo)
    ImageView app_logo;
    Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mActivity = this;
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(app_logo, "app_logo");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("transition_name", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(app_logo));
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity,app_logo,ViewCompat.getTransitionName(app_logo));
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/application_logo"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/application_logo"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:tint="@android:color/black"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mActivity = this;
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
        ImageView application_logo = (ImageView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.application_logo);
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                String imageTransitionName = extras.getString("transition_name");
                application_logo.setTransitionName(imageTransitionName);
                ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(mActivity);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the Sample code for `SharedElementTransition` according to your scenario. Whenever you use some kind of style always write in style file then use it.

> Note: `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` for ToolBar in Java file. This is working fine.